# Number of ways to assign $8$ subjects to $4$ people s.t. one gets an odd number of subjects

Tags: combinatorics

I am asked to find the number of ways to assign $8$ subjects to $4$ people, such that the third person always gets an odd number of subjects.

What I did was consider the problem as putting indistinguishable objects (subjects) in distinguishable boxes (people) and came to the following:

1. pick $7$ subjects and assign them to the first, second and fourth person, and give the remaining subject to the third person;
2. pick $5$ subjects for the three people and assign the remaining $3$ to the third person;
3. pick $3$ subjects for the three people and assign the remaining $5$ to the third person;
4. pick $1$ subject for the three people and assign the remaining $7$ to the third person.

Giving me the following solution (using combinations with repetition):
$$
{7 + 3 - 1 \choose 2} + {5 + 3 - 1 \choose 2} + {3 + 3 - 1 \choose 2} + {1 + 3 - 1 \choose 2}
$$

Are my solution and thought-process okay? Additionally, what should I do if the subjects as well as the people are considered distinguishable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the subjects are indistinguishable you are right.

If they are distinguishable,

- choose $1$ subject for the third person. . . . . $8$ ways
- choose a person for each remaining subject. . . . . $3^7$ ways

. . . and similarly if the third person gets $3,5$ or $7$ subjects.  See how you go.

Answer (score 1):

The basic tenet of the suggested solution is that subjects are distinguishable while persons are not, apart from one particular individual. Whether the 3rd or any other of the 4 persons is this pivotal recipient does not matter. So you may resort to a case-by-case analysis for all numbers of subjects possibly allotted to the person singled out. What's left to do is counting the possible mappings of the number of remaining subjects to the remaining number of unidentified persons.

$N =  {8 \choose 1} \sum_{i=0}^7 ( \sum_{j=0}^{7-i} ( 7-i-j ) )  / 3! \\
\quad\quad +  {8 \choose 3} \sum_{i=0}^5 ( \sum_{j=0}^{5-i} ( 5-i-j ) ) / 3! \\
\quad\quad\quad +  {8 \choose 5} \sum_{i=0}^3 ( \sum_{j=0}^{3-i} ( 3-i-j ) ) / 3! \\
\quad\quad\quad\quad +  {8 \choose 7} {3 \choose 1}$

The first factor in each of the sum's terms denotes the number of possibilities of choosing a given odd number of subjects while the term's remainder counts the number of assignments of the remaining subjects to indistinguishable persons.